# Pointer loses value (simplistic code)

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is the code:

```
#include "DynIntStack.h"


DynIntStack::DynIntStack(void)
{
}


DynIntStack::~DynIntStack(void)
{
}

bool DynIntStack::IsEmpty()
{
    return head;
}
void DynIntStack::Push(int v)
{
    Element e = Element(v, head);
    head = &e;
}
int DynIntStack::Pop()
{
    if(head)
    {
        int r = head->v;
        head = head->next;
        return r;
    }
}
int DynIntStack::Top()
{
    if(head)
        return head->v;
}
string DynIntStack::Print()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "IntStack {";
    Element *k = head;
    while (k)
    {
        ss << k->v << ", ";
        k = k->next;
    }
    ss << "}";
    return ss.str();
}
```

The "head" pointer seems to lose its value every time I call push. Why?
Often times the head element will contain a pointer to ITSELF, which should not be possible with this code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you create object on stack, when object goes out of scope it's destroyed. As a result `head` becomes dangling pointer, since it references freed memory.

```
void DynIntStack::Push(int v)
{
    Element e = Element(v, head);
    head = &e;
}
```

What you need to do is to allocate object on heap, something like this:

```
Element * e = new Element(v, head);
head = e;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know c++ had a garbage collector

Comment: @user1071988: C++ does not have GC. But objects allocated on stack are destroyed when they go out of scope.

Comment: Okay, so when exactly are objects created on the stack ?

Comment: @user1071988: When you don't allocate them explicitly on the heap with new or malloc. I propose to read [this nice discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) about the subject.

Comment: Well, I don't see declaration of `head`, but I can conclude this is 100% pointer, because you: 1. assign pointer to it. 2. compare it with NULL (`if(head)`). It's clearly a pointer, you simply can't do this kind of things with non-pointer.

Comment: Where is the space for class members allocated ? My guess would be the heap, but can't I initialize them without malloc / new ? Couln't I change head to a non pointer and write head = Element(v, &head) ?

Comment: I believe 'head' must be a pointer (or smart pointer), that's just fine for your needs. Comments are for requesting clarification, not for "follow-up questions". I suggest you to spend some time now learning the C++ basics and come back in a few days if you still can't work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your program exibits undefined behavior in `Top()`. When `head == NULL`, the function doesn't return anything - all gloves are off afterwards.

Same with `Pop`, which also appears to be implemented incorrectly. Running the code through a debugger would help.